# Debugging eclipse unit test code "Test class should have exactly one" and "Workspace is closed" error

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, debugging, junit

I'm trying to build eclipse plugins (org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests.refactoring).

[image]

Downloading the source from the git, and I could build the project.
I wanted to debug into ExtractMethodTest routine, I  just set a breakpoint in a setUP routine, and launch the debugger.

[image]

However, I got an initialization error.

[image]

Then, I tried to launch the debugger by right click on the `ExtractMethodTests.java` in package explorer to get `Workspace is closed` error.

[image]
[image]
What might be wrong? I just wanted to launch `ExtractMethodTests.java` unit test to trace the code line by line.

Comment: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests.refactoring/test%20cases/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/tests/refactoring/AllTests.java which calls http://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.ui.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests.refactoring/test%20cases/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/tests/refactoring/AllRefactoringTests.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to run with the wrong version of JUnit? Eclipse ships with both JUnit 3 and Junit 4 compatible runtimes.

Secondly, does your unit test actually have a 0-arg constructor?

Clearly, I didn't check the code base to see if the Eclipse people know how to create the unit tests. I'm just assuming they do.

Answer (score 0):

### "Test class should have exactly one" error

Using JUnit 3 as a test runner solved the first issue, but I still have the workspace issue. I'll open another post for it.

[image]

### "Workspace is  closed" error

From the hint of [Workspace is closed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200960/workspace-is-closed-error), I executed the test as a plugin test to make it work.

[image]