# Difference between `JUnit Plug-in Test` and `JUnit Test` in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, junit, workspace

In the eclipse run command, there are two choices: `JUnit Plug-in Test` and `JUnit Test`.

[image]

Before, I tried to launch eclipse plugin test (`org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests.refactoring`), and I had some issues ( [Debugging eclipse unit test code "Test class should have exactly one" and "Workspace is closed" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889273/debugging-eclipse-unit-test-code-test-class-should-have-exactly-one-and-works) ).

The issue was that when I tried to launch the debugger with  `JUnit Test`, I got `Workspace is closed` error.

[image]

In eclipse configuration, they have the same workspace.

[image]
[image]

- What is the difference between the two? And especially, how does workspace work for them?
- Why I have `Workspace is closed` error with JUnit Test run? Is it possible to launch eclipse plugin test with `JUnit Test`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JUnit Plug-in test is for testing Eclipse plug-ins. It runs a new instance of Eclipse. Then, it runs the tests.

JUnit test is for testing regular Java applications. It runs the tests without launching a new instance of Eclipse.